# Is it possible to have remote backup to a WHS?

Tags: backup, remote, windows-home-server

Is it possible to have computers remotely connect and backup to a Windows Home Server? I have 3 machines for which the initial backup would be done locally but then they will be remote for most of the time.

I have another 3 machines that will remain local to where the server is planned to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a VPN.  I like hardware VPNs, but you could try something like [Hamachi2](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/).  If WHS and the remote clients were on the same VPN it may work.  There could be a problem with WHS's firewall because it is configured to restrict connections to the local subnet.  WHS may not count Hamachi2's subnet as local, but this can be reconfigured.  [This post](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/whsfaq/thread/295498e9-de53-46c8-9d38-7f110bdb2aeb) should get you in the right area.

If you go with a hardware VPN, you could use something similar to Netgear ProSafe Firewall/VPN appliances.

Hope this helps.